# How to show a Validation error on UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to create an error on a textfield validation very similar to this one:

[image]

I understood there is some native iOS red icon that I can show on the validation error?

How can I achieve something like that?

Do you know of a library or a piece of code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any native iOS validation error indicator, you have to use your own image.

So you can set `UIImageView` with your own validation error image as `rightView` of your TextField

```
yourTextField.rightView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage"))
yourTextField.rightViewMode = .always
```

---

Now inside some `delegate` method set `isHidden` of `rightView` of your TableView depending on your condition

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { // for example when editing did end
    textField.rightView?.isHidden = isEverythingCorrect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Assign `rightView` to `UITextField`

2- Conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textfield.delegate = self
        let img =  UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "02"))
        img.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        textfield.rightView = img
        textfield.rightViewMode = .always
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let content = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)  
        textField.rightView!.isHidden = content.count % 2 == 0 
        return true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you give more exmaple on how to use this code ?